# css: how to target p a img

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, css-selectors

```
<p><a href...><img... /></a></p>
```

The links have a border and raquo after them in the css, like so:

```
 p a:after, .content li a:after {content: "\00a0 \00bb";}
```

How can I target just images within a link inside a paragraph to remove this styling?
Using this later in the css isn't working:

```
a img, #logo a, p a img {border:none;text-decoration:none;}
        a:after img {content:"";}
```

UPDATE:
 Did a search and replace to add a class:

```
<p><a ([^<]*)><img
<p><a class="imagelink" $1><img
```

then used this css:

```
   a.imagelink {border:none;} a.imagelink:after {content:"";}
```

Comment: You are applying stuff to the `a` tag, not to the `img` so you can't remove it.

Comment: I was thinking 'img' was a child of 'a' but now understand it is content, not an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is simply not possible.  There is no "parent selector" in CSS, so you cannot select an element based on an element that it may contain.

There are many alternatives, but all of them will require updating the anchor tag itself in some way such as adding a class.

```
p a.img-container:after { content: "" }
```

Comment: OK, I thought maybe some fancy > or + would get me there. Was trying to apply globally without editing the html, but will search/replace to add a class. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to "target images within a link inside a paragraph", you will need to use this CSS selector:

`p a img{Your code}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create style attributes in a new CSS class to reverse what you specified in

```
p a:after, .content li a:after {content: "\00a0 \00bb";}
```

Sample CSS

```
.clearStyle{ /*attributes*/  }
```

Comment: I'll add a class. I was thinking backwards.